# How do i know what kind of network I am having?

Tags: windows-7

I use usb modem to access to internet through an ISP. its a broadband internet connection. So I know definitely I am not on a Public(wifi) network.

but there are other two types called Home network and Working network.

So I am on which of these?

thanx in advance for an appropriate answer.

Comment: Are you physically at Home or Work?  Chances are you are at home so it Home network.

Comment: @cybernard I am at my Home ( I didn't work at office currently)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the connection icon on the task bar. Select "Open network and sharing centre". It will tell you there.

Comment: It just says "Mobile Broad Band Connection 2". Nothing else.

Comment: The one it's connected to should show. Can you "View active networks"?

Comment: there is no view "view active network"